# Create xfs system with mfks

Tags: centos, centos7, xfs, zenoss, mkfs

I'am following a guide to install Zenoss which asks me to create a xfs system. 
To do this I need to run the following command:

```
mkfs -t xfs Partition
```

The guide says as follows:
'Replace Partition with the path of the target primary partition'

What would be that partition?

Output of lsblk:

```
  NAME             SIZE
    sda             30.4G
    └─sda1            10G
      └─centos-root   10G
    sr0             1024M
```

Comment: You have to create a new partition on your disk (ie sda2) and then use it in command `mkfs -t xfs /dev/sda2`. Check/Find some guides on how to create a new partition (for example via fdisk http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Partition/fdisk_partitioning.html)

Answer (score 1):

As explained by @[calvix](https://serverfault.com/users/326103/calvix), you would need a partition first.

Looking at your `lsblk` output, you seem to be using LVM, which I assume means /dev/sda has been assigned to a LVM VolumeGroup (VG).

This in turns gives you two basic options:

- create a new LV (Logical Volume) on your existing LVM VG (see `lvcreate`), and then format that LV to xfs
- or add another hard drive (or something that presents like one, e.g. an iSCSI target), and either format it to xfs directly, or do the necessary LVM-fu on it to get something you can format.

The only other suggestion I can think of is to see if you could just provision your machine with XFS from the start (i.e. make your existing partitions XFS), but you may have reasons why that approach doesn't work for you.